# How could I restore old logs of Yarn?

Tags: hadoop, logging, hadoop-yarn, restore

Is there a way to recover old logs stored on logs folder of Yarn ?

I want to see the history of the two previous weeks and I can't since these logs were deleted, or moved to another folder.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Job History server enabled then it will clean them based on the `mapreduce.jobhistory.max-age-ms` settings.  So unless you have some backup enabled or are running HDFS snapshots there is no way to recover these logs.

[How long does the Hadoop Resource Manager store the application information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44781337/how-long-does-the-hadoop-resource-manager-store-the-application-information/44838608#44838608)

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsSnapshots.html